# Property of action of a group ring on cyclotomic Galois extension

Tags: galois-theory, group-actions, cyclotomic-fields

I want to understand one of the properties of the action of a group ring on cyclotomic Galois extension.

If $\zeta_n$ is primitive root of unity, $G = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) / \mathbb{Q})$ and $f : G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is an element of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, the action of $f$ on an element $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is defined as:
$$x^f = \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x)^{f(\sigma)}$$

The property I'm trying to prove is:

$$(x_1 + x_2)^f = x_1^f + x_2^f$$

My calculations go like this:

$$(x_1 + x_2)^f = \prod_{\sigma \in G}\sigma(x_1 + x_2)^{f(\sigma)} = \prod_{\sigma \in G}(\sigma(x_1) + \sigma(x_2))^{f(\sigma)}$$

$$x_1^f + x_2^f = \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x_1)^{f(\sigma)} + \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x_2)^{f(\sigma)}$$

Don't know how to finish the proof. Any help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you see it is not true. $x^f = \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x)^{f(\sigma)}$ is an action of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ on the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)^*$

Comment: What user1952009 says! $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)^*$ becomes a $G$-module, but the "addition" operation of this module is the multiplication of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)^*$. Your identity cannot possible hold. For an obvious example consider the case of $f=2*1_G$, when $x^f=x^2$.

Comment: @user1952009 thank you for the answer. I saw the statement in [this article](https://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwje2pb-o67UAhXFtBoKHZkUCYwQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fyadda.icm.edu.pl%2Fyadda%2Felement%2Fbwmeta1.element.baztech-article-BAT3-0013-0012%2Fc%2Fhttpwww_itl_waw_plczasopismajtit2004469.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGmHCLM7DsdJ-jD-9JcFocgKvGCOA&sig2=PuzZYOzreexfqeOemr-YGw) (on the 3rd page) and in the Henri Cohen's book A course in computational Algebraic number theory (447 page). Is the statement really completely wrong?

Comment: Did you read what Jyrki wrote ? It is true if you replace $+$ by $\times$ the multiplication of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)^*$.

Comment: Yeah, @user1952009, I read it. But did you saw the article I linked in my previous comment? There are given both of the properties $(x_1 + x_2)^f = x_1^f + x_2^f$ and $(x_1x_2)^f = x_1^fx_2^f$. I agree that the second one is OK, but the first one...

Comment: They meant $x^f = (\prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma^{f(\sigma)})(x)$ where $\prod$ is the composition of automorphisms

Comment: No the example 5 says they really meant $x^f = \prod_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(x)^{f(\sigma)}$  so that's just a (huge) typo @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @user1952009: Surely they mean that $f=2\cdot1_G$ (or, if you prefer, the function that maps $1_G$ to $2$ and the other automorphisms to zero) acts by squaring its input rather than by applying the identity automorphism twice. The latter doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: IOW: we surely want
$$x^f=\prod_{\sigma\in G}\sigma(x)^{f(\sigma)}$$ and not
$$x^f=\left(\prod_\sigma \sigma^{f(\sigma)}\right)(x).$$ The product
$\prod_\sigma \sigma^{f(\sigma)}$ makes sense in the group $G$, but here we want to act by an element of $\Bbb{Z}[G]$. I actually suspect that we agree on this, but the comments may not be crystal clear :-)